# Is a documentation of Blitz++ matrices available?

Tags: documentation, matrix-multiplication, blitz++

**Is a documentation of Blitz++ matrices available?**

I found http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz//manual/blitz01.html with google, but this seems not to contain the documentation.

The only useful example I found is this one from [Rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication):

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <blitz/tinymat.h>

int main()
{
  using namespace blitz;

  TinyMatrix<double,3,3> A, B, C;

  A = 1, 2, 3,
      4, 5, 6,
      7, 8, 9;

  B = 1, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 1;

  C = product(A, B);

  std::cout << C << std::endl;
}
```

But this small example doesn't answer many of my questions:

- Does something like BigMatrix exist?
- How can I create matrices when I don't know their size at compile time?
- Which other operations do these matrices support?

A search for tinymat.h revealed this folder:

```
moose@pc07:/usr/include/blitz$ ls
applics.h      matbops.h     ops.h           tinyvec-et.h   vecglobs.h
array          matdiag.h     prettyprint.h   tinyvec.h      vecio.cc
array.h        matexpr.h     promote.h       tinyvecio.cc   veciter.h
array-impl.h   matgen.h      promote-old.h   tinyveciter.h  vecmax.cc
array-old.h    mathf2.h      rand-dunif.h    traversal.cc   vecmin.cc
bench.cc       mathfunc.h    rand-mt.h       traversal.h    vecnorm1.cc
benchext.cc    matltri.h     rand-normal.h   tuning.h       vecnorm.cc
benchext.h     matref.h      random.h        tvcross.h      vecpick.cc
bench.h        matrix.cc     randref.h       tvecglobs.h    vecpick.h
blitz.h        matrix.h      rand-tt800.h    update.h       vecpickio.cc
bzconfig.h     matsymm.h     rand-uniform.h  vecaccum.cc    vecpickiter.h
bzdebug.h      mattoep.h     range.h         vecall.cc      vecsum.cc
compiler.h     matuops.h     reduce.h        vecany.cc      vector.cc
config.h       matutri.h     shapecheck.h    vecbfn.cc      vector-et.h
etbase.h       memblock.cc   tau.h           vecbops.cc     vector.h
extremum.h     memblock.h    timer.h         veccount.cc    vecuops.cc
funcs.h        meta          tiny.h          vecdelta.cc    vecwhere.cc
gnu            minmax.h      tinymatexpr.h   vecdot.cc      vecwhere.h
indexexpr.h    mstruct.h     tinymat.h       vecexpr.h      wrap-climits.h
limits-hack.h  numinquire.h  tinymatio.cc    vecexprwrap.h  zero.cc
listinit.h     numtrait.h    tinyvec.cc      vecglobs.cc    zero.h
```

So I guess `Matrix` is for bigger matrices. But how do I multiply them? Additionally, this is not my preferred way to learn something about a library.

I have `libblitz-doc - C++ template class library for scientific computing` installed, so the documentation should be on my computer. But where do I have to search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [www.oonumerics.org](http://www.oonumerics.org) website seems to be broken at the moment. However the full documentation for Blitz is included with the package which can be downloaded from [this link](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/blitz/blitz/Blitz++%200.9/blitz-0.9.tar.gz) on SourceForge.

In Blitz there is no special class like `BigMatrix`. Matrix is just a two-dimensional array, so use the `Array` template. You don't have to know the size of an array/matrix at compile time. Here's a small example from the docs:

```
#include <blitz/array.h>

using namespace blitz;

int main()
{
    Array<int,2> A(6,6), B(3,3);

    // Set the upper left quadrant of A to 5 
    A(Range(0,2), Range(0,2)) = 5; 

    // Set the upper right quadrant of A to an identity matrix
    B = 1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 1;
    A(Range(0,2), Range(3,5)) = B;

    // Set the fourth row to 1
    A(3, Range::all()) = 1;

    // Set the last two rows to 0
    A(Range(4, Range::toEnd), Range::all()) = 0;

    // Set the bottom right element to 8
    A(5,5) = 8;

    cout << "A = " << A << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you are using Debian-based distribution, `dpkg -L libblitz-doc` will reveal the content of the `libblitz-doc` package and you could see where the docs are located. On my machine they are in `/usr/share/doc/libblitz-doc/`